# Как отсортировать гистограмму в plotly по убыванию?

Tags: python, графика, plotly

мой код:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def hist(x):
    return messages[x].value_counts()

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x = hist('kmeans').index,
                      y = hist('kmeans').values))
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack', xaxis = {'categoryorder': 'total descending'})
fig.show()
```

Ввожу этот код, который подсчитывает количество значений каждого класса, но гистограмма получается следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, гистограмма строилась по убыванию значения Y.

Столбец датафрейма, по которому хочу построить график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы проще, если бы был кусок датафрейма messages

Comment: а зачем сортировать `гистограмму`?

Comment: выложил кусок датафрейма

Comment: @strawdog чтобы красивее выглядело и понятнее было, какой столбец больше

Comment: так гистограмма не для красоты. гистограмма для оценки

Comment: @strawdog ответил выше

Comment: данные в коде должны быть в вопсроизводимом виде, а не скриншотом

Comment: я бы не вашем месте не сортировал, а делал, например, цветовую дифференциацию...

Comment: @strawdog код представлен в обычном для него виде, а скриншотами только график и часть датафрейма, чтобы все было понятно

Comment: я вам про данные и говорю. у вас их запросили для воспроизведения кода. а вы скриншот прилепили.

Comment: @strawdog я не могу выложить эти данные в stackoverflow. Суть не в них, а в сортировке, нужен универсальный код для любых данных

Comment: ясно. ждите тогда, пока кто-то сжалится и нагенерит данных за вас или ваш вопрос закроют.

Comment: Попробуйте взять в качестве `x = range(len(hist('kmeans').values))`, там значения `value_counts()` уже отсортированы по убывающей, нужно просто в качестве `x` взять значения по порядку. Но так вы не будете понимать, каким `x` реально соответствуют ваши `y`.

Comment: @strawdog я не жду, пока кто-то сжалится. Если человек знает, как это сделать для любых данных, то пусть напишет сюда. Если не знает, то пускаем вопрос на самотек. Это всего лишь формальность в моей задаче, поэтому могу спокойно прожить)

Comment: Вы бы уже пятьдесят раз могли добавить пример данных. Ну, хозяин-барин.

Comment: @strawdog да ладно уже, спасибо за дифференциацию)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая на ваш вопрос и не более, могу сказать, что отсортировать можно так:

```
messages = messages.sort_values(by='kmeans')
```

где-то в начале. НО

Это не сработает, видимо, из-за `go.Bar()`, который все равно преобразует по индексам и сортировка летит лесом.

Как найду решение этой проблемы, дополню ответ

UPD:
Если по иксу числа - то `plotly` сортирует. Строки - нет, поэтому вот решение:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x = list(map(str, hist('kmeans').index)),
                      y = hist('kmeans').values))
```

Comment: `.value_counts()` и сам уже сортирует данные, их не нужно дополнительно сортировать

Comment: @окей, понял, тогда только после UPD